# Dynamically add and rotate a geometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Refer https://jsfiddle.net/pmankar/svt0nhuv/

Main large red icosahedron geometry keeps rotating about the y axis. I added a small red sphere geometry and merged it to the main large red icosahedron geometry. Until here it works fine. For this I used, `THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(point_sphere_iso_geom, sphere);`

However, when I try to add spheres dynamically with a mouse click, they are added (yellow spheres), but they do not rotate with the main large red icosahedron geometry.

Can anyone explain why does it works in the initial case, but not when added dynamically and how to achieve it dynamically as well.

Comment: Maybe because the mesh is created **after** the geometries have been merged when initializing the app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly. Every mouse click you have to create a new geometry based on the previous one (mesh geometry and mesh matrix), merging it with the geometry of a new sphere, and apply it to a new mesh, then remove the old mesh and add the new one.

some changes in vars

```
var geometry, material, point_sphere_iso_geom, mesh;
```

in creation of the start merged mesh

```
point_sphere_iso_geom = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(100, 4);
cygeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 10, 10);
cygeo.translate(0,0,120);
point_sphere_iso_geom.merge( cygeo );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(point_sphere_iso_geom, material);
```

and in the function of addYellowPoint

```
function addYellowPoint(valX, valY) {
    var sgeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2.5, 10, 10);

    var range = 150;
    var x = Math.random() * range - range / 2;
    var y = Math.random() * range - range / 2;
    var z = Math.random() * range - range / 2;
    sgeometry.translate(x,y,z);
    point_sphere_iso_geom = mesh.geometry.clone();
    point_sphere_iso_geom.applyMatrix(mesh.matrix);
    point_sphere_iso_geom.merge(sgeometry);

    scene.remove(mesh);
    mesh.geometry.dispose();
    mesh.material.dispose();
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(point_sphere_iso_geom, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Now the problem is, I wanted the dynamically added geometry (cubes) to have different material (that has a different color). I updated the code according to your suggestions [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmankar/svt0nhuv/8/). Is it possible to use some sort of group and rotate the complete geometry within a group together.

Comment: To be honest, I see no reason to work with merging of geometries then. Why simply not to add yellow objects straight to the big sphere (icosahedron). [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/ad1w0tjq/)